# Dynamic Animation

Tags: unity

I want this plane to fly to the blue cube. I want to be able to animate its flight in Unity or in external software. The problem is that I don't know exactly where this cube will be during the game.

[image]

What are the best ways to do that? What functionality / assets / plugins to use?

Comment: Is the cube an unique gameObject or there can be multiples in the scene? Because if it is a single one, you could just create a public gameObject variable in a script attached to the plane and from there you can use the cube's position to steer the plane's direction. Regarding the flight animation, however, could you explain a bit more what kind of animation are you looking for?

Comment: Yes there will be only one cube. Let's say that I want the plane to rotate around its roll axis a bit to the sides and also so that its propeller will be rotating.

Comment: I will not post it as an answer as it is just a suggestion and I cannot properly elaborate it now, anyway it seems to me that rather than using an animation, you could actually perform a rotation on its rigidbody around an axis. you might check out here: https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform.Rotate.html